# Why does Xcode present me with "You are not permitted to remove provisioning profiles from this team" when exporting ipa?

Tags: ios, xcode, profile, provisioning

I normally export an ad hoc `.ipa` package at the end of each day using Xcode 6.1.1. Today when I selected the build from the Organiser and attempted to export it I was presented with this error:

[Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues. You are not permitted to remove provisioning profiles from this team. Please contact one of your team admins, who can remove the profile on your behalf.](http://puu.sh/et0FZ/8aa77e2885.png)

I haven't attempted to remove any provisioning profiles and can't seem to find where I could have done this.

I'm certain something has changed on the Member Centre but I did not change anything. The most anyone knows is that someone requested a device uuid to be added this morning.

I've tried removing all files from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and downloading the latest profiles and certificates again and I have ensured that the Target's profile is correct. I haven't had any success. This error hasn't changed at all over the last 3 hours I've tried to address it.

Any insight into what might have changed to break this would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up with a solution? Could you share it? We have transfer the Agent Role to another user and I'm experiencing the same problem...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what happened in the end. We ended up resigning everyone's certificates and basically starting from scratch. This includes the whole Keychain Access "Request Certificate from a Certificate Authority" thing.

Answer (score 2):

If the provisioning profile that Xcode is trying to automatically create already exists, it will instead perform an update. In order to perform an update, it needs to be able to remove the existing one and add a new one. If you are missing either remove or add permission, you will be unable to have Xcode update existing provisioning profiles.

It sounds like the provisioning profile that it's trying to use does not include the certificate that you have installed. You will need to manually create a provisioning profile in the iOS Dev Centre and then link to this profile when exporting.

Comment: looks like we will have to wait for the admin to come in tomorrow to do this. i've sent them an email and will update this stackoverflow question tomorrow. thanks for the advice!